# Firepit burner safety limitations indoor

Tags: fireplace

I wanted to put a high BTU burner into a fireplace that only has a "log lighter" burner in it now, but one brand I had reached out to said "our burners aren't approved for indoor use, due to the high BTU output"

This is a vented fireplace which is rated to be able to burn wood. Are there any considerations I should be aware of when finding a high powered burner to swap into here?

I wouldn't think exhaust would be an issue since wood can be burned, and I also wouldn't think heat output would matter since with coals and logs burning, the heat could be quite intense, but I'm asking to be safe given the comment made by that manufacturer.

Comment: You ought to be checking with the manufacturers making the burners. They would know better than us.  Plus, if you install a unit that isn't approved, say good bye to any homeowner's insurance coverage in case of fire or damage.

Comment: Can google for the numbers, but I think gas has a much higher BTU output than wood/coal in a limited space.

Comment: At least part of the reason gas has replaced wood & coal in furnaces.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

Google for "indoor gas fireplace insert". Preferably get one with a blower so that you're not strictly wasting heat up the flue.

You need to make sure your flue can handle the BTU.

---

> I wanted to put a high BTU burner into a fireplace that only has a "log lighter" burner in it now, but one brand I had reached out to said "our burners aren't approved for indoor use, due to the high BTU output"

Okay, a picture of the current situation would be nice. What brand did you reach out to? What model number did you inquire about?

> This is a vented fireplace which is rated to be able to burn wood. Are there any considerations I should be aware of when finding a high powered burner to swap into here?

Yes, consult a chimney/fireplace company. At minimum you'll want it inspected and cleaned. If you get someone nice then you can inquire about your gas fireplace plans and they ***might*** provide some insight into way to not burn down your house.

> I wouldn't think exhaust would be an issue since wood can be burned, and I also wouldn't think heat output would matter since with coals and logs burning, the heat could be quite intense, but I'm asking to be safe given the comment made by that manufacturer.

Sorry to be blunt but your opinion does not matter and neither does mine when it involves a fireplace. Consult a chimney/fireplace company.

The manufacturer has zero clue about the health of your existing fireplace and they'd rather lose your business as a customer than face the legal woes of you burning your house down due to their guidance.

Comment: Glad I asked - thanks